# match two dataframes for partial strings in R

Tags: r, dplyr, match, left-join

For example I want to match this dataframes by using variable feature and feature2 according to the corresponding string.

```
Dataframe1                        Dataframe2
    Object price feature             person   feature2
    house  20     205                Johnson   1122056
    car    50     710                Lewis     4Dl-open75
    window 40     open               Lewis     ltkgreen
    garden 100    green              Hill      111710D
```

Which should give me a result like this.

```
Object price feature person 
house   20    205    Johnson
car     50    710    Hill
window  40    open   Lewis
garden  100   green  Lewis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this relatively simple by creating a column of partially matched dataframes and then just unnest that.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- tibble(
  Object = c('house','car','window','garden'),
  price = c(20,50,40,100),
  feature = c('205','710','open','green')
)

df2 <- tibble(
  person = c('Johnson','Lewis','Lewis','Hill'),
  feature2 = c('1122056','4Dl-open75','ltkgreen','111710D')
)

result <- df1 %>%
  mutate(
    df2 = lapply(feature, function(x){df2 %>% filter(grepl(x, feature2))})
  ) %>%
  unnest(df2)
```